# CSS: Grid column takes up more space than is necessary

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The grid column takes more space than is necessary for the item to fit in.It is the last item in the grid. If I try to set bigger width to the element it keeps expanding both ways and even though it has space on the right side ( as shown on the picture ).

Do you guys know why the grid is giving it additional space?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add 'overflow-hidden' to the grid container to see what happens? Also don't use fixed width 'w-32' instead use 'w-full'.

Comment: This kinda helps but I was wondering more about what is causing the empty space if no padding nor margin is pushing the width of the column? Because I want the button to have a set width and if I use the w-full it just stretches the button from end to end as there is no other content in the grid.

The problem is that if I add some content to the row above it is not centered on the button